# CalendarList month not showing in react-native-calendars

Tags: react-native, calendar

I am using this but I am facing issue that month is cutting in it so I am able to see Only 20% of JUN from top in month name. I am not able to get what is the problem in this.

```
import {
  Calendar,
  CalendarList,
  Agenda,
  Calander,
} from "react-native-calendars";

 <CalendarList
                current={calendarDate}
                style={styles.calanderStyle}
                markingType={"custom"}
                theme={{
                  // backgroundColor: "rgb(31,35,43)",
                  calendarBackground: "rgb(31,35,43)",
                  textSectionTitleColor: "#ffffff",
                  textSectionTitleDisabledColor: "#ffffff",
                  selectedDayBackgroundColor: "#ffffff",
                  selectedDayTextColor: "#ffffff",
                  todayTextColor: "#ffffff",
                  dayTextColor: "#ffffff",
                  textDisabledColor: "#d9e1e8",
                  dotColor: "#00adf5",
                  selectedDotColor: "#ffffff",
                  arrowColor: "rgb(101,180,84)",
                  // disabledArrowColor: 'red',
                  monthTextColor: "white",
                  indicatorColor: "blue",
                  textDayFontFamily: "ProximaNova-Regular",
                  textMonthFontFamily: "ProximaNova-Regular",
                  textDayHeaderFontFamily: "ProximaNova-Regular",
                  textDayFontWeight: "400",
                  textMonthFontWeight: "bold",
                  textDayHeaderFontWeight: "200",
                  textDayFontSize: 15,
                  textMonthFontSize: 2,
                  textDayHeaderFontSize: 11,
                }}

                horizontal={true}
                onDayPress={(day) => apiCallingFunction(day.dateString)}
                caleendarWidth={300}
                markedDates={calandarEvents}
              />
```

Comment: Can you add a screenshot of your result?

Comment: Can you share your styles and also a screen shot of what you are getting

Answer (score 0):

Try adding padding to the container the CalendarList is in.